# Getting Quattrocento as math font in article class

Tags: fonts, math-mode

in beamer I can do this

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{quattrocento}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Quattrocento ${30\cdot40}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and both the text and the math font will be printed in the Quattrocento font.

How do I achieve the same in the article class? If I do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{quattrocento}

\begin{document}

Quattrocento ${30\cdot40}$

\end{document}
```

only the text font is changed and not the math

Pics:

beamer

[image: http://imgur.com/svyPgVM]

article

[image: http://imgur.com/t1zeC7w]

Comment: There is no math font accompanying Quattrocento.

Comment: @egreg so why in beamer the font does change? The changed font is not Quattrocento?

Comment: The `beamer` class tries to be smart and uses the italic font in the main document family for the letters in math mode.

Comment: @egreg ok, so the question is: how do I achieve the same smart behavior in the article class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's as easy as loading a package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{quattrocento}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\begin{document}

Quattrocento $30\cdot40+ab-c$

\end{document}
```

[image]