# problem with math font and LuaLaTeX

Tags: beamer, fonts, math-mode, luatex

The following code works fine if compiled in pdflatex:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{quattrocento}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Quattrocento $30\cdot40$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As is explained by egreg in my previous question ([Getting Quattrocento as math font in article class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144655/getting-quattrocento-as-math-font-in-article-class/144681#144681)) beamer automatically uses the text font for letters and numbers in mathmode.

Now I need to compile my presentation with LuaLaTeX, so I changed the code to:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setsansfont{Quattrocento}
\setmathfont{Quattrocento}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Quattrocento ${30\cdot40}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However in this way the `\cdot` is not printed (I'm assuming because the symbol is not in the Quattrocento font, and now the font is used for all math symbols, not only letters-numbers).

How can I restore beamer behavior with pdflatex when using lualatex?

Comment: Quattrocento doesn't qualify as a math font. Don't load `unicode-math`, add the option `no-math` to `fontspec` and load `mathastext` as in the other case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quattrocento doesn't qualify as a math font for `\setmathfont`; fonts for this purpose should be specially tailored for math, with hundreds of symbols and some internal tables.

You can, for limited purposes, use `mathastext`, but you have also to load `fontspec` with the `no-math` option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{quattrocento}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Quattrocento $30\cdot40+ab-c$           
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `${30\cdot 40}$` is not necessary; adding braces could even be dangerous if not done properly: better remove them.

Comment: yes, sorry, the braces are the result of some experiments I was doing before posting, I'll remove them from the question. Thank you.